# Error WATSNGWERR-0x0113001c means what?

Tags: ibm-cloud, speech-to-text, watson

```
$ curl -X POST -u "057e842a-ece8-4825-8199-e77053a64a9e":"xxx" --header "Content-Type: audio/flac" --data-binary "@meeting2.flac" "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?timestamps=true&customization_id=0ae89a90-955e-11e7-9e8b-53863e154a1c"
curl: (55) SSL_write() returned SYSCALL, errno = 32
{ "code" : 500 , "error" : "Server Error" , "description" : "2017-09-09T10:36:46-04:00, Error WATSNGWERR-0x0113001c occurred when accessing https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?timestamps=true&amp;customization_id=0ae89a90-955e-11e7-9e8b-53863e154a1c, Tran-Id: stream-dp01-2524637048 - Watson Gateway Error" }
```

and

```
$ curl -X GET -u "057e842a-ece8-4825-8199-e77053a64a9e":"xxx" "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/customizations/0ae89a90-955e-11e7-9e8b-53863e154a1c"
{
   "owner": "410e0660-26a8-4ee0-ba09-e101df7961e0",
   "base_model_name": "en-US_BroadbandModel",
   "customization_id": "0ae89a90-955e-11e7-9e8b-53863e154a1c",
   "dialect": "en-US",
   "created": "2017-09-09T12:54:40.057Z",
   "name": "sprint2",
   "description": "sprint2",
   "progress": 0,
   "language": "en-US",
   "status": "ready"
}
```

The model exists, and it seems to be ready (however, I'd expect progress = 100 in this case but anyway), but for some reason, I can't use it.

Any clue on what this error message mean?

Ps. if I use the default model (not the customized one) it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status `ready` means it is ready for training, not ready for using.

So you need to invoke the `/train` API to make it `available` for using and the `progress` will be `100` once it is `available`.

**To invoke the `/train` API:**

```
$ curl -X POST -u "057e842a-ece8-4825-8199-e77053a64a9e":"xxx" \
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/customizations/0ae89a90-955e-11e7-9e8b-53863e154a1c/train"
```

Optional, you can specify a customization weight while training.

Wait a while, you should get

```
$ curl -X GET -u "057e842a-ece8-4825-8199-e77053a64a9e":"xxx" "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/customizations/0ae89a90-955e-11e7-9e8b-53863e154a1c"
{
   "owner": "410e0660-26a8-4ee0-ba09-e101df7961e0",
   "base_model_name": "en-US_BroadbandModel",
   "customization_id": "0ae89a90-955e-11e7-9e8b-53863e154a1c",
   "dialect": "en-US",
   "created": "2017-09-09T12:54:40.057Z",
   "name": "sprint2",
   "description": "sprint2",
   "progress": 100,
   "language": "en-US",
   "status": "available"
}
```

This document is helpful: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/speech-to-text/language-create.html#trainModel

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your customization model(`0ae89a90-955e-11e7-9e8b-53863e154a1c`) is in an inconsistent status.

Try deleting the customization and creating a new one?

#### Deleting a customization

```
$ curl -X DELETE -u "057e842a-ece8-4825-8199-e77053a64a9e":"xxx"\
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/customizations/0ae89a90-955e-11e7-9e8b-53863e154a1c"
```